# Android Kotlin Gradle build failed

Tags: android, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'android' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

How should I fix this error?

Comment: You fix it by reading the error message and fixing what it says. In this case, upgrade your Kotlin version from 1.3.50 to 1.5.20 or newer. I recommend 1.8.20, which is the latest at the time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your project, you have a **build.gradle** file.

That is where you define your Kotlin compiler version.

The current Android Gradle Plugin (or AGP) that you are using works with a minimum version of Kotlin 1.5.20.

So you need to change the line where it states the Kotlin compiler version is 1.3.50 to 1.5.20.

```
plugins {
    ...
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.5.20" apply false
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin)

Comment: I do not see that plugins block on build.gradle.

Comment: @EshikaJagani - Please share your project level build.gradle file (edit your answer and add it).